# Pyinstaller: jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: swagger-ui.html

Tags: pyinstaller, swagger-ui, flask-restful

I developed a REST API with `flask_restful` and deployed it with the help of `waitress`. To document the API, I am using `FlaskApiSpec` from `flask_apispec.extension`. Everything works fine when I execute the app.py. I packaged the app via `pyinstaller` into one bundled executable file. Running the .exe file, I get the following error when I call `/swagger-ui`:

```
2023-07-12 14:51:26 app ERROR Exception on /swagger-ui/ [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "flask\app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
  File "flask\app.py", line 1822, in full_dispatch_request
  File "flask_restful\__init__.py", line 271, in error_router
  File "flask\app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
  File "flask\app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request
  File "flask_apispec\extension.py", line 96, in swagger_ui
  File "flask\templating.py", line 146, in render_template
  File "jinja2\environment.py", line 1081, in get_or_select_template
  File "jinja2\environment.py", line 1010, in get_template
  File "jinja2\environment.py", line 969, in _load_template
  File "jinja2\loaders.py", line 126, in load
  File "flask\templating.py", line 62, in get_source
  File "flask\templating.py", line 98, in _get_source_fast
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: swagger-ui.html
```

The command I am using to package the app.py:

```
pyinstaller -w --onefile app.py
```

Do I need to add another arguments to pyinstaller?

If the info helps: I am runing the app in a virtual environment.